# Variable "auto escaping" from a string?

Tags: php, string, variables, escaping

I'm an amateur php programmer and it's been a while since I last did some coding. Now, I'm using php to generate some html content. I was surprised to see thet php did some auto escaping. Is this normal behavior? I remember that before I couldn't just embed variables into text without escaping first.

```
$my_variable = 1;
echo "I'm outputting some text and $my_variable gets value: ".$my_variable."<br>";
```

This actually outputs: 
    I'm outputting some text and 1 gets value: 1\ŋ

Should it work like this and if it should, is it advisable to just let variables to "auto escape" from a string?

Comment: If you place your text within single quotes it won't get parsed as a PHP variable.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are expanded in double quoted strings. To prevent this, you can escape the $ sign by adding a backslash in front of it:

```
echo "I'm outputting some text and \$my_variable gets value: ".$my_variable."<br>";
```

or, if you want to put the auto-expansion to use:

```
echo "I'm outputting some text and \$my_variable gets value: $my_variable<br>";
```

Note that not only variables, but also special character escapes, like `\"` (double quote), `\n` (newline) and `\t` (tab) are expanded.

Alternatively, use a single quoted string. In a single quoted string, nothing is expanded. The only characters you need to escape in a single quoted string are `'` and `\`.

```
echo 'I\'m outputting some text and $my_variable gets value: '.$my_variable.'<br>';
```

For more details about the difference between single quoted and double quoted strings (and the other available string types), see the PHP documentation here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php